# Preventing users from deleting a Slack app's messages

Tags: slack-api

Probably a simple question, but how can one post a message as an app that user's cannot delete? I've been prototyping an app and, to my surprise, as a user, I can delete all of the messages posted by the app. Didn't expect that! Am I missing a setting somewhere?

I am using the `app.client.chat.postMessage()` functionality in the context of a Bolt app.

Is it maybe because I am the workspace owner? Although I don't remember seeing any documentation to that effect...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can delete any message posted by the app in Direct Message Context. But you cannot delete a message posted by the app in Private Channel.

Comment: What about a message posted in a public channel? I've definitely seen apps where you could not delete the messages so I know it's possible.